# How to stop SonarQube from collecting branch statistics?

Tags: git, maven, sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube (5.5) for running metrics on a project, this project build via maven and is versioned via Git

Is there any chance to only keep the statistics of my `master` branch and trash the statistics run from any `feature/*` branches?

Comment: That's just how SonarQube works. Perhaps you could [edit] your question to expand on your scenario and what you're trying to achieve...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my understanding is correct the main issue here is that you're analyzing both the master and the feature branches without using the "sonar.branch" property. I would advice in a first time to stop analysing feature branches.